# For loop sticking after nested while loop completion or after break

Tags: c

The following is a piece of code to iterate through a list of file names and check if they are equal to the file name I am looking for.  They are piece files so I have to use sprintf to check for a particular section of the file.

```
for(i = 1; i < 4; i++){
    bzero(filebuf, 500);
    sprintf(filebuf, ".%s.%d",filebuf2, i);
    strcpy(fileslist2, fileslist);
    tok = strtok(fileslist2, "|");
    while(tok != NULL){
        tok = strtok(NULL, "|");
        if(strcmp(tok, filebuf) == 0){
            printf("Equal!\n");
            i = 5;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

the idea here is that if the file is found I need to break out of both loops.  But right now if it finds the file the code just stops.  Also, if the file is not there then the for loop needs to iterate and continue looking for the next piece.  This is not happening either, after tok == NULL it just hangs as well. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you find when you step through your code in your debugger?  As it stands, it's difficult to give you much guidance without seeing more code.  I think you should show the definitions of `fileslist2`, `fileslist`, `filebuf`, and `filebuf2`, and show how `fileslist` and `filebuf2` are populated.

Comment: Possible `strcmp(NULL, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

A minor modification that may help prevent a `strcmp` on `NULL`

```
for(i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
  bzero(filebuf, 500);
  sprintf(filebuf, ".%s.%d",filebuf2, i);
  strcpy(fileslist2, fileslist);
  tok = strtok(fileslist2, "|");
  while(tok != NULL) {
      // tok = strtok(NULL, "|"); // moved down
      if(strcmp(tok, filebuf) == 0) {
          printf("Equal!\n");
          i = 5;
          break;
      }
      tok = strtok(NULL, "|"); // to here
  }
}
```